# Apktool 2.3.3-dirty : Error During APK Recompilation

Tags: apktool

**What I Am Trying To Do?**

I am trying to decompile a apk file , modify it and recompile it again.

**What is my working Environment?**

```
root@l0calh0st:~/Desktop/APKS/Projects# uname -a
Linux l0calh0st 4.15.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.15.17-1kali1 (2018-04-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**What I Have Done?**

1. `apt-get update 
   apt-get full-upgrade`
2. `apt-get install apktool`
3. Reference to [https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/] I decompile a apk using `apktool d RAR_v5.60.build56.apk` command and i succeed.

But without even modifying the file when i tried to recompile it using `apktool b RAR_v5.60.build56` command i got something like this:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.3.3-dirty
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: aapt: brut.common.BrutException: brut.common.BrutException: Could not extract resource: /prebuilt/aapt/linux/aapt (defaulting to $PATH binary)
W: A/        ( 2465): First type is not attr!
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 134): [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 17, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 56, --version-name, 5.60.build56, --no-version-vectors, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL6407896023935370654.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, arsc, -I, /root/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /root/Desktop/APKS/Projects/RAR_v5.60.build56/res, -M, /root/Desktop/APKS/Projects/RAR_v5.60.build56/AndroidManifest.xml]
```

**What is wrong? I need a solution. Please help.** Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem by uninstalling Apktool 2.3.3-dirty and installing Apktool 2.3.3 from official website. Also I replaced openjdk-10 by jdk-1.8. Sorry for being so stupid.

Answer (score 5):

Try clearing framework dir:

```
$ apktool empty-framework-dir
```

Solved problem for me

Answer (score 0):

we can use --use-aapt2 flag.
apktool_2.5.0.jar b --use-aapt2 -f -d -p apt_folder -o app.apk

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to some files are missing after the recompilation, so it is showing we cant rebuild the apk, files required to compile the apk **:**

[image]

these are the required files to build apk with apktool b command. Files after decompiling the apk **:**

[image]

You can see in both the images, 2 files are missing after the recompilation I don't know why but you can still edit the decompiled files and again drag the missing two files
The files are available in the github repo(AndroRAT) check once you will get the idea.

Comment: Maybe it's a great answer but if you use msfvenom to do this, you can't add the miss file dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem, and i just didnt compile the resources using following command:

```
apktool d -r <package-name>
```

!change the package-name!